# Fallout Shelter Restore Mr Handy Purchase

Tags: fallout-shelter

I bought Mr. Handy on another device. My save didn't transfer to my new device. Is there anyway I can restore the purchase?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Mr. Handy purchases are tied to the specific vault.

You can try to contact Bethesda, and they can evaluate the situation.